# Update amount using Rx

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs

I have 2 `Subject` (plusOne[itemId], minusOne[itemId]) that emit item ids which amount should be altered by one (either added or subtracted).

The user can send multiple signals with the same item id. Ultimately, I want to subscribe to an `Observable` that would emit a `Pair[itemId,amountToSet]`

UI looks like a list of item rows each of which contains "+" and "-" buttons which trigger corresponding onNext(itemId).

I've tried thinking of solving problem with by grouping itemids and reducing the sequence, but the problem is that `reduce` only kicks in when `onCompleted` is called, while my subjects are not supposed to complete their emissions.

Here's code that can't utilize reduce:

```
plusItem.asObservable().groupBy(id -> id).subscribe(new Action1<GroupedObservable<Long, Long>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(GroupedObservable<Long, Long> groupedObservable) {
        System.out.println("Composed a group with key: " + groupedObservable.getKey());
        groupedObservable
                .map(id -> 1)
                .startWith(0)
                .reduce((integer, integer2) -> integer + integer2)
                .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Integer sum) {
                        System.out.println(Integer.toString(sum));
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

**Solution**

```
private Observable<Pair<Long,Integer>> getUpdateObservable(
    Observable clickSource,
        Observable<Map<Long,Integer>> initValues,
        Func1<Long,Integer> groupMapFunc

) {
    return clickSource
            .asObservable()
            .groupBy(id -> id)
            .flatMap(new Func1<GroupedObservable<Long, Long>, Observable<Pair<Long, Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Pair<Long, Integer>> call(GroupedObservable<Long, Long> groupedObservable) {
                    return groupedObservable
                            .map(groupMapFunc)
                            .scan((integer, integer2) -> integer + integer2)
                            .withLatestFrom(initValues, new Func2<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>, Integer>() {
                                @Override
                                public Integer call(Integer integer, Map<Long, Integer> basket) {
                                    return basket.get(groupedObservable.getKey()) + integer;
                                }
                            })
                            .map(new Func1<Integer, Pair<Long, Integer>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Pair<Long, Integer> call(Integer integer) {
                                    return new Pair<>(groupedObservable.getKey(), integer);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

Can you suggest anything?

Thanks!

Comment: rxjs is the tag for reactive extensions for JavaScript

Comment: @paulpdaniels, so what? I don't mind getting suggestions from javascript community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#scan(R,%20rx.functions.Func2)) will return the intermediate values

```
plusItem
  .asObservable()
  .groupBy(id -> id)
  .subscribe(new Action1<GroupedObservable<Long, Long>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(GroupedObservable<Long, Long> groupedObservable) {
        System.out.println("Composed a group with key: " + groupedObservable.getKey());
        groupedObservable
                .map(id -> 1)
                .scan(0, (integer, integer2) -> integer + integer2)
                .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Integer sum) {
                        System.out.println(Integer.toString(sum));
                    }
                });
    }
});
```